Django: problem with adding apps to isntalled apps when they are moved from root directory
i am using django 4.2 . the project was working when apps were in base directory ( where manage.py locates) , then i created an apps directory and moved the apps to this directoryso the structure is like this ( partially) :
/project/
        /manage.py
        /config/
             /settings/
                      / base.py # base settings file
                      / local.py
                      / testing.py
                      / __init__.py
            /__init__.py
      /requirements/
      /siteapps/
           /products/
                    / (file of products app including __init__.py 
           /accounts/
                    / (file of accounts app including __init__.py
           / (other apps)
           /__init__.py
          



and this is  related code i use in base.py settings :
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent

print(f"base dir => {BASE_DIR}")
# output :
# base dir => /code 
# /code is base directory is docker container the project running in.
print("path =>", sys.path)
# output: 
# path =>  ['/code', '/usr/local/lib/python311.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages']

INSTALLED APPS = [
 ... # other apps including django's and third parties,
 # LOCAL APPS
    "siteapps.accounts.apps.AccountsConfig",
    "siteapps.products.apps.ProductsConfig",
]

the error i get is :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 982, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 212, in create
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'accounts'. Check that 'siteapps.accounts.apps.AccountsConfig.name' is correct.

so my problem is when apps located in base directory i could add them to installed apps without problem , but now i moved them to apps directory i've been constantly getting error. i tried different ways but still getting the same error. my question is how can i organasied my apps if i cannot move them from root directory? i am very new to django , any helo will be appreciated

can you show the apps.py content of each of your apps? lets see if it is configured properly. 2. also check for Uppercase and lower case mismatch in your apps (accounts) apps.py

This is a terribly unusual pattern for Django projects, why did you decide to do that? We usually keep the original layout (apps at the project root, same level as manage.py), unless there's a compelling reason to nest further. In your case every app's apps.py should be updated to replace 's/name = "(.+)"/name = "siteapps.\1"/'.

the problem solved by editing name in apps.py.
@STerliakov i am inexperienced programmer, self taught myself from zero in the last 14 months, i am just experiencing things, in this case i prefered this sructure, is there anything bad going to  happen with this structure? my aim was to organaize.

Well, nothing will just "be bad". If such organization makes more sense for your specific project - that's definitely fine (see e.g. django-allauth, where providers submodule contains about 50 app for different auth providers - it's definitely logical to group them in a module). If your apps are fully isolated (congrats! I never reached such perfection in production), then you won't need to adjust imports, but otherwise all your cross-app imports will need updates too. And ForeignKey string references. And a multitude of other places where Django accepts dotted paths.

It's just terribly difficult to do such migration on a mid-sized and large codebases.

thank you @STerliakov . been fine so far but i definitely going to have a research on the things you mentioned.
